# pipenv / pipfile - Install different package version in dev

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

Is it somehow possible to install a different version of a Python package in dev? Obviously the Pipfile coul look like following:

```
[packages]
awesome-package = "==1.2.3"

[dev-packages]
awesome-package = {editable = true, path = "./../../../awesome-package"}
```

Ideally I would like to switch between a stable version and a locally modified version of a package, when running `pipenv install ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my own answer. The solution is to manage multiple virtual environments per project. Pipenv didn't support that natively. However you can manage multiple Pipfiles in subdirectories.

My default Pipfile still resides in the project root. Other virtual environments I maintain in subfolders within the directory `pipfile.d`:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── pipfile.d
    └── local-dev
        └── Pipfile
        └── Pipfile.lock
```

To use a different virtual env I just cd into the `local-dev` directory, run my `pipenv shell` and cd from there back to the root directory.

Comment: Too much hassle though...